# Why do I get a ValueError in Python for the line some_nparray.size == 0?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am writing a function which takes a NumPy array as a parameter and processes it in a certain way. Naturally, as a first step I want to make sure that the argument passed by the user is not an empty array.

Intuitively, I tried using the following:

1.

```
if len(some_array) == 0:
    return None
```

2. 

```
if some_array.size == 0:
    return None
```

but in both cases I get the following error:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

which points to the above mentioned conditions in the if-statements.

I do understand why the truth value of *an array* can be ambiguous, but here I just want to check the size of an array. When I test `len()` or `np.ndarray.size` on different possible inputs, I always get the desired output, so I'm not sure why this error is raised in my case.

I also do not see how I could make use of `a.any()` or `a.all()`, since I do not want to test the properties of the separate elements, but rather just a specific property of the array as a whole.

I am new to NumPy, so maybe this is a very obvious question, but I would really appreciate help, since I couldn't find an answer to this specifically!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also post an example of `some_array` where the condition is failing when it should be passing?

Comment: @Ananda I couldn't seem to find it. For instance if `some_array = np.array([1,2,3])` then `len(some_array) == 0` or `some_array.size == 0` both yield false, as expected, cause the length of my array is actually 3. But if I call the function: `my_function(some_array)` I get the above mentioned error.

Comment: OK, then, show the function.  Because otherwise we can't reproduce.  Or at least I can't

Comment: print `some_array.size == 0` without the `if` to check

Comment: Hi, when asking a question we always love https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  minimal reproducbile example so we can test and run the code to see what is going on.